# Passing pointers to threads without being out of scope

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am given a pre-defined .lib files of pre-defined classes/functions.

I will need to create a:

```
    Cdefined *p = new Cdefined;
    p->Init();
```

in the main() program to init my class object before calling my thread.

However I realised that in each of my threads, I will have to call:

```
    p->doProcess();
```

to run a segment of the code, for each of the threads.

However, this function will not work unless i call `p->Init()`.

Since now I have at least 2 scopes of p (one created in `main()`, and N of them in N threads), how do I go about designing my thread, such that the class can be passed in without scope errors? [My constrain is that `p->Init()` has to be called in `main()`]

Comment: Can you say "This is a really terrible interface and requirement"?

Answer (score 4):

If the object's lifetime is simply bound to the scope of `main`, then that's easy - just make sure you've stopped and joined all the threads before destroying the object. This can be better enforced either by managing the object with a smart pointer scoped within `main` or, more simply, by giving the object automatic lifetime within `main`:

```
void thread_func(Cdefine *);

int main()
{
    Cdefine thing;
    thing.Init();

    std::thread thread1(thread_func, &thing);
    std::thread thread2(thread_func, &thing);

    // do stuff

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    // Now it's safe to destroy the object
}
```

In a more complicated situation, where you can't simply bind the object to a wider scope than that of the threads, you could consider managing it with `std::shared_ptr` (or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` if you're stuck with the pre-2011 language). For example:

```
void thread_func(std::shared_ptr<Cdefine> p);

void spawn_threads()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Cdefine> p = std::make_shared<Cdefine>();
    p->Init();

    std::thread thread1(thread_func, p);
    std::thread thread2(thread_func, p);

    thread1.detach();
    thread2.detach();

    // The threads can carry on doing their thing, and it's safe to
    // drop our shared pointer. The object will be deleted when the
    // last thread drops its pointer to it.
}
```

As an aside, why on earth do you need to call an `Init` function after constructing the object? Why not initialise it in the constructor, since that's what a constructor is for?

Comment: Thanks.The     Init() function comes about due to the requirement of the library i was using; i could not modify its individual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Create one instance of `Cdefined` for each thread, calling its `Init` method, and pass it as an argument to the thread.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
{
    Cdefined *p = new Cdefined;
    p->Init();
    create_thread(thread_func, p);
}
```

And the thread function:

```
void *thread_func(void *data)
{
    Cdefine *p = reinterpret_cast<Cdefine*>(data);

    for (;;)
    {
        // Do stuff...
        p->doProcess();
        // Do other stuff
    }

    return 0;
}
```